# How to find probability of posterior parameter with Winbugs

Tags: bayesian, winbugs, mcmc

My winbugs code is as follows:

```
model
{
    for ( i in 1:N){ logit(p[i])<- alpha+ beta*x[i]
        y[i]~ dbin(p[i], n[i])
    }

    alpha~ dnorm(0,0.000001)
    beta~ dnorm(0,0.000001)
    pbeta<-step(beta-0)
}

list(N=20,
n=c(6, 7, 6, 8, 8, 5, 6, 6, 5, 8, 6, 5, 7, 6, 6, 7,6 , 6, 7, 3),
y=c(0,2,6,2,2,1,3,6,2,3,4,3,7,0,1,0,0,1,1,2),
x=c(25.7, 32.3, 49.6, 35.2, 35.9, 33.2, 39.8, 51.3, 32.9, 40.9,
43.6, 42.5, 50.4, 36.5, 34.1, 31.3, 28.3, 36.5, 37.4, 40.6))
list(alpha=0.1, beta=0.2)
```

After running this code, I have posterior distribution of alpha and beta. Now I want to see `P(beta>0)`. They said that I can use `pbeta<- step(beta)` (pbeta is treated like a dummy variable: 0 if `beta=0` and 1 if `beta>0`). But when I put it in the model it gave me an error notification.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong with your code, and it runs for me.  What was the error message?

On an unrelated matter, your MCMC chains should converge more efficiently if you center the covariate values around their mean.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually, now it runs. I do not know why, I did the same thing but it only worked at the end of the day.